# Consulta SQL tarda mucho tiempo en laravel y en phpmyadmin muy poco

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo una consulta que involucra 6 tablas, en laravel tarda 26 segundos en mostrar el resultado y en phpmyadmin 0.0089 segundos.

[image: Foto de phpmyadmin]

[image: Resultado en laravel]

Este es el código en laravel:

```
use DB;    
$partidas = DB::select("SELECT A.Patente, A.Pedimento, A.SeccionAduanera, A.Fraccion, A.SecuenciaFraccion, A.ValorComercial, A.PrecioUnitario, A.CantidadUMComercial, A.UnidadMedidaComercial, A.CantidadUMTarifa, A.UnidadMedidaTarifa, A.MetodoValorizacion, A.PaisOrigenDestino, A.PaisCompradorVendedor,  
                                                B.ClavePermiso, B.NumeroPermiso, 
                                                C.ClaveCaso, C.IdentificadorCaso, C.ComplementoCaso, 
                                                D.ClaveContribucion, D.FormaPago, D.ImportePago, 
                                                E.TasaContribucion, E.TipoTasa, 
                                                F.Observaciones
                                        FROM `551` A
                                        INNER JOIN `553` B ON B.Fraccion = A.Fraccion
                                                AND (A.SecuenciaFraccion = B.SecuenciaFraccion)
                                                AND (A.auditoria_id = 4 AND B.auditoria_id = 4)
                                                AND (A.Patente = '3452' AND B.Patente = '3452')
                                                AND (A.Pedimento = '0000180' AND B.Pedimento = '0000180') 
                                                AND (A.SeccionAduanera = '430' AND B.SeccionAduanera = '430')
                                        INNER JOIN `554` C ON C.Fraccion = A.Fraccion 
                                                AND (A.SecuenciaFraccion = C.SecuenciaFraccion)
                                                AND (A.auditoria_id = 4 AND C.auditoria_id = 4)
                                                AND (A.Patente = '3452' AND C.Patente = '3452')
                                                AND (A.Pedimento = '0000180' AND C.Pedimento = '0000180') 
                                                AND (A.SeccionAduanera = '430' AND C.SeccionAduanera = '430')
                                        INNER JOIN `557` D ON D.Fraccion = A.Fraccion 
                                                AND (A.SecuenciaFraccion = D.SecuenciaFraccion)
                                                AND (A.auditoria_id = 4 AND D.auditoria_id = 4)
                                                AND (A.Patente = '3452' AND D.Patente = '3452')
                                                AND (A.Pedimento = '0000180' AND D.Pedimento = '0000180') 
                                                AND (A.SeccionAduanera = '430' AND D.SeccionAduanera = '430')
                                        INNER JOIN `556` E ON E.Fraccion = A.Fraccion 
                                                AND (A.SecuenciaFraccion = E.SecuenciaFraccion)
                                                AND (A.auditoria_id = 4 AND E.auditoria_id = 4)
                                                AND (A.Patente = '3452' AND E.Patente = '3452')
                                                AND (A.Pedimento = '0000180' AND E.Pedimento = '0000180') 
                                                AND (A.SeccionAduanera = '430' AND E.SeccionAduanera = '430')
                                        INNER JOIN `558` F ON F.Fraccion = A.Fraccion 
                                                AND (A.SecuenciaFraccion = F.SecuenciaFraccion)
                                                AND (A.auditoria_id = 4 AND F.auditoria_id = 4)
                                                AND (A.Patente = '3452' AND F.Patente = '3452')
                                                AND (A.Pedimento = '0000180' AND F.Pedimento = '0000180') 
                                                AND (A.SeccionAduanera = '430' AND F.SeccionAduanera = '430')
                                        ");
                dd($partidas);
```

Por el momento tengo los valores estáticos para hacer pruebas pero serán con variables.

¿Sabrán por qué tarda tanto? y/o si es mejor hacer la consulta de otra forma para obtener más rendimiento.

Gracias!!

Agrego el explain y ese si lo hace rápido:

[image: Explain 1]
[image: Explain 2]

Comment: La única vía efectiva para poderte ayudar es que le hagas un EXPLAIN a esa consulta y agregues el resultado de la misma aquí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias al usuario pablov o pablete de discord por haberme ayudado a resolver mi pregunta!

Cabe aclarar que hice pruebas quitando tablas, por ejemplo empecé con A y B, funciono normal, ABC etc hasta que con F empezaba el problema de lo lento, supongo que fué por tantas tablas y registros que tenia que revisar, hasta que pablete me dio esta opción y funcionó.

La sentencia quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
$partidas = DB::select("SELECT A.Patente, A.Pedimento, A.SeccionAduanera, A.Fraccion, A.SecuenciaFraccion, A.ValorComercial, A.PrecioUnitario, 
                                        A.CantidadUMComercial, A.UnidadMedidaComercial, A.CantidadUMTarifa, A.UnidadMedidaTarifa, A.MetodoValorizacion, A.PaisOrigenDestino, 
                                        A.PaisCompradorVendedor, 
                                        B.ClavePermiso, B.NumeroPermiso, 
                                        C.ClaveCaso, C.IdentificadorCaso, C.ComplementoCaso, 
                                        D.ClaveContribucion, D.FormaPago, D.ImportePago, 
                                        E.TasaContribucion, E.TipoTasa, 
                                        F.Observaciones 
                                FROM `551` A 
                                LEFT JOIN `553` B ON B.Fraccion = A.Fraccion AND (A.SecuenciaFraccion = B.SecuenciaFraccion) AND (A.auditoria_id = B.auditoria_id) AND (A.Patente = B.Patente) AND (A.Pedimento = B.Pedimento) AND (A.SeccionAduanera = B.SeccionAduanera) 
                                LEFT JOIN `554` C ON C.Fraccion = B.Fraccion AND (B.SecuenciaFraccion = C.SecuenciaFraccion) AND (B.auditoria_id = C.auditoria_id) AND (B.Patente = C.Patente) AND (B.Pedimento = C.Pedimento) AND (B.SeccionAduanera = C.SeccionAduanera) 
                                LEFT JOIN `557` D ON D.Fraccion = A.Fraccion AND (A.SecuenciaFraccion = D.SecuenciaFraccion) AND (A.auditoria_id = D.auditoria_id) AND (A.Patente = D.Patente) AND (A.Pedimento = D.Pedimento) AND (A.SeccionAduanera = D.SeccionAduanera) 
                                LEFT JOIN `556` E ON E.Fraccion = A.Fraccion AND (A.SecuenciaFraccion = E.SecuenciaFraccion) AND (A.auditoria_id = E.auditoria_id) AND (A.Patente = E.Patente) AND (A.Pedimento = E.Pedimento) AND (A.SeccionAduanera =  E.SeccionAduanera) 
                                LEFT JOIN `558` F ON F.Fraccion = A.Fraccion AND (A.SecuenciaFraccion = F.SecuenciaFraccion) AND (A.auditoria_id = F.auditoria_id) AND (A.Patente = F.Patente) AND (A.Pedimento = F.Pedimento) AND (A.SeccionAduanera = F.SeccionAduanera)
                                Where A.auditoria_id = 4
                                And A.Patente = '3452'
                                And A.Pedimento = '0000180'
                                And A.SeccionAduanera = '430'
                                ");
```

El LEFT JOIN yo lo modifique porque no me daba los resultados como esperaba, pero no afecto en el rendimiento